# Retaining gridview data inside multiview

Tags: vb.net, gridview, multiview

I have  views inside a multiview container. View1 has a gridview to which, I bind data extracted from Database. Apart from that, I have added a LinkButton in the grid. View 1 will be active on page load.

On click of link button in grid, I have to display the details in the row from which I clicked the link button, in next active view. Problem here is, I'm not able to retain the selected grid row's details.

I tried recovering selected row data by giving CommandName as "Select" for the link button.I can fetch the selected row index. But, when I access the data by the below code, I get null reference exception.

```
Dim r as Integer
Dim dr As DataRow
r=grid1.SelectedRow.RowIndex 'Here, I get RowIndex properly.
For i As Integer = 1 to 5
dr(i)=grid1.Rows(i).Cells(i).Text 'I get Null reference error because Text has nothing.
Next
```

Sorry for not giving all the code part. Let me know if more information needed. I want to know, if data can be retained throughout all views in the multi-view container or should I go with other alternative.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, shouldn't you go like this:

```
Dim r as Integer
Dim dr As DataRow
r=grid1.SelectedRow.RowIndex 'Here, I get RowIndex properly.
For i As Integer = 1 to 5
dr(i)=grid1.Rows(r).Cells(i).Text 'I get Null reference error because Text has     nothing.
Next
```

Notice `grid1.Rows(r)` instead of `grid1.Rows(i)`

Comment: HEre I have written by mistake. In my code, its fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have set the value as CommandArgument of Link button and fetched details from DB according to the value. Issue sorted. But, one more DB hit!